# First 8 bytes is truncating in AES decryption in java where encryption is done in c#

Tags: java, security, aes

I am trying to decrypt the string which is encrypted in c# with same key length and vector.

JAVA CODE

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String cum006333 = decrypt("h+VJ5or2yBFQYawNWXET11nekUzWYYVWk0/O2fHxoLNm60l3d3qQo2NJjGr3+zZP", "MYPRIVATE@KEY");
        System.out.println(cum006333);

    }

    public static String decrypt(String cipherText, String passphrase) {
        String s = null;
        try {

            Cipher   cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeyFactory  factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            
            byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);
            int keySize = 256;
            int iterCount = 1000;

            int ivLength = 16;
            byte[] saltByte = new byte[]{0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76};
            byte[] ivB = Arrays.copyOf(bytes, ivLength);
            byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,ivLength, bytes.length);

            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), saltByte, iterCount, keySize);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivB);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(data);
            s = new String(original);
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }

    
}
```

expexted output is - Duplicate Request ID

output coming is  - e Request Id

I need to encrypt the request in java and send to api where they will decrypt it and use it. So i want java equivalent of the below C# code..

please find C# code used for encrypting and decrypting below

```
public static string EncryptResponse(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SECRETMSG"].ToString();
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = rfcdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = rfcdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryp = new CryptoStream(mem, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryp.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cryp.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(mem.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }


    public static string DecryptResponse(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SECRETMSG"].ToString();
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = rfcdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = rfcdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryp = new CryptoStream(mem, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryp.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cryp.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(mem.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm sorry but your data isn't running through decrypt properly but shows an error on my device: "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption" - that means that something in your data isn't correct. Without seeing the c#-code it's difficult to help you, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't like to mix answers I'm writing a second answer with the final solution for your question.

Thanks for providing the C#-code as it answered 2 questions - what is the **encoding** of the plaintext and what data is included in the **ciphertext**.

Using this line on C# shows us that the encoding is UNICODE (=UTF 16) as I argued in my first answer:

```
byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
```

To get identical results in Java you need to decode any decryption result with

```
s = new String(original, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
```

The second question - what is included in the ciphertext is answered very simple - just the ciphertext itself (**no IV**). The neccessary IV is derived by the

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes...
encryptor.Key = rfcdb.GetBytes(32);
encryptor.IV = rfcdb.GetBytes(16);
```

Putting both information together I can decrypt the ciphertext with the given key as follows:

```
First 8 bytes is truncating in AES decryption in java where encryption is done in c#
cipherByte length: 48 data: 87e549e68af6c8115061ac0d597113d759de914cd6618556934fced9f1f1a0b366eb4977777a90a363498c6af7fb364f
keyDerived length: 32 data: e35b88684a86fe06ae80eab429b2c9c242ab64f225649aa484ced8f53e5de146
ivB        length: 16 data: 19b9e11cb1e6c6aa69060fbdfe10484c
original   length: 40 data: 4400750070006c006900630061007400650020005200650071007500650073007400200049004400
Duplicate Request ID
Duplicate Request ID
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class mainSo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("First 8 bytes is truncating in AES decryption in java where encryption is done in c#");
        String cipherstring = "h+VJ5or2yBFQYawNWXET11nekUzWYYVWk0/O2fHxoLNm60l3d3qQo2NJjGr3+zZP";
        byte[] cipherByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherstring);
        System.out.println("cipherByte length: " + cipherByte.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(cipherByte));
        String cum006333 = decrypt(cipherstring, "KEY@CRISIL123");
        System.out.println(cum006333);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String cipherText, String passphrase) {
        String s = null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);
            int keySize = 256;
            int iterCount = 1000;
            int ivLength = 16;
            byte[] saltByte = new byte[]{0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76};
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), saltByte, iterCount, (keySize + (8 * ivLength))); // 32 + 16
            byte[] rawKey = factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(); // 48 bytes
            byte[] keyDerived = Arrays.copyOf(rawKey, (keySize / 8)); // first 32 bytes
            byte[] ivB = Arrays.copyOfRange(rawKey, (keySize / 8), rawKey.length); // last 16 bytes
            System.out.println("keyDerived length: " + keyDerived.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(keyDerived));
            System.out.println("ivB        length: " + ivB.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(ivB));
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyDerived, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivB);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            //byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(data);
            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
            System.out.println("original   length: " + original.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(original));
            s = new String(original, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it worked, kindly mark this answer as "accepted", thanks.

Comment: Hi Micahel,  Need one more help, please can you assist for what changes need to done for encryption logic as i have tried with changing below line but didn't work.. 
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            //byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(data);
            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(cipherText.getBytes());
            byte[] original1=Base64.getEncoder().encode(original);

Comment: The question was about decrypting in Java that was encrypted in C# - so your new problem demands a new question, thanks. Just a note - on the **decryption** side the input is a base64 encoded string - for **encryption** you can leave this out for the input part but have to append it at the end.

Comment: i have added a question can you please help me on this , 
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386104/aes-encryption-not-giving-expected-result

Answer (score 1):

What a shame that you don't show us the encryption code in C# as it would point us directly to the solution instead of arguing and searching.

The reason for your claiming of "truncating" is not on Java-side (decryption) but on your c# encryption function. Most probably you are using a UTF-16 encoding for your plaintext but on Java-side the standard encoding (UTF-8) takes place.

Below you find a slightly added version of your code with dedicated outputs for your data to be fore sure all data has the right length.

Having a look on the ".doFinal" output we see a value of (hex) "`650020005200650071007500650073007400200049004400`" - a lot of "x00" values between each character that is definitely a UTF-16 encoding, so in the end the string value **is not** "`e Request Id`" but "`e   R e q u e s t   I D`".

Changing the "new String" encoding to "`new String(original, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)`" get the "correct" output of "e Request ID" - but where is the missing
"Duplicat" in the beginning? I'm sure you are getting the (base64 encoded) string of ciphertext by "Array-copying" as well and you are just copy the last 12 (or 24 in UTF-16) bytes of the ciphertext so - what I am believing - you are truncating the ciphertext on C#-side.

output

```
First 8 bytes is truncating in AES decryption in java where encryption is done in c#
cipherByte length: 48 data: 87e549e68af6c8115061ac0d597113d759de914cd6618556934fced9f1f1a0b366eb4977777a90a363498c6af7fb364f
ivB        length: 16 data: 87e549e68af6c8115061ac0d597113d7
data       length: 32 data:                                 59de914cd6618556934fced9f1f1a0b366eb4977777a90a363498c6af7fb364f
original   length: 24 data: 650020005200650071007500650073007400200049004400
e   R e q u e s t   I D
e   R e q u e s t   I D
```

change code line

```
s = new String(original);
to
s = new String(original, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
```

gives:

```
e Request ID
```

code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class mainSo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("First 8 bytes is truncating in AES decryption in java where encryption is done in c#");
        String cipherstring = "h+VJ5or2yBFQYawNWXET11nekUzWYYVWk0/O2fHxoLNm60l3d3qQo2NJjGr3+zZP";
        byte[] cipherByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherstring);
        System.out.println("cipherByte length: " + cipherByte.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(cipherByte));
        String cum006333 = decrypt(cipherstring, "KEY@CRISIL123");
        System.out.println(cum006333);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String cipherText, String passphrase) {
        String s = null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);
            int keySize = 256;
            int iterCount = 1000;
            int ivLength = 16;
            byte[] saltByte = new byte[]{0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76};
            byte[] ivB = Arrays.copyOf(bytes, ivLength);
            byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,ivLength, bytes.length);
            System.out.println("ivB        length: " + ivB.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(ivB));
            System.out.println("data       length: " + data.length + " data:                                 " + bytesToHex(data));
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), saltByte, iterCount, keySize);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivB);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(data);
            System.out.println("original   length: " + original.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(original));
            s = new String(original);
            //s = new String(original, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for support ...its a third party api.. i am using and at client end they are using c# ..so that code is not available..with me..i am trying will update as it is available...

Comment: Hey i have updated the c# code please find in edits